# Using article in one sentence

Tags: word-usage, articles

how do i say "Have a great Sunday and a productive week ahead!"?
or without article before "productive week", like "Have a great Sunday and productive week ahead!"

Thanks!

Comment: This sentence looks great.

Answer (score 1):

> "Have a great Sunday and a productive week (ahead)!"

is OK.

Indefinite article "a" is needed at least for reasons of parallelism with "**a** great Sunday".

Comment: I don't think parallellism enters into it. You'd need _**a** productive week_ even if Sunday weren't mentioned.

Comment: @ColinFine: you are right, but I might not have the good explanation about the "why" :D Therefore, I took the shorter path ;)

Answer (score 0):

The odd thing is not that we need an article before *productive week* - "week" is a singular countable noun, so it needs an article.

The odd thing is that we need an article before *great Sunday*: "Sunday" is a proper name, and doesn't normally require an article.

But when we qualify proper names (for example with adjectives or relative clauses) we often do require an article.

Answer (score -1):

In your example

> productive week ahead

sounds too bulky, better and more succcint might be

> Have a great Sunday and a productive week.  *(following week is implied)*
>   Have a great Sunday and a productive next week.

Comment: I don't agree that there's anything wrong with it, and I find your last suggestion borderline ungrammatical.